# Можно ли объединить библиотеку vosk(на python) и arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, vosk

Просто мне надо знать, через Arduino делать или RasberryPi. Если Arduino, то какая модель лучше всего подойдёт? Мне надо это знать, так как я хочу сделать игровой автомат на голосовом управлении(проект).

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Arduino явно не подойдёт для обработки голоса.

Answer (score 0):

нет нельзя, python язык интерпретируемый, в то время как на Ардуино используется язык C++ а он компилируемый

к тому же Ардуино не умеет быстро обрабатывать голосовые команды, но можно осуществить чтение за ранее записанных файлов с карты памяти